# Dynamic Countif in vba

Tags: excel, vba, countif

Trying to create dynamic ranking based off of what is in cell F2 +1. I know I'm probably missing something stupid/minor, can someone please help me out?

```
Sub Formula1()


Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim wsLOB As Worksheet, wsClient As Worksheet

Set wsLOB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("P&C LOB Data")
Set wsClient = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All P&C Client Data")

For i = 2 To lastrow1
    If wsClient.Cells(i, 6) = "" Then
        wsClient.Cells(i, 5) = ""
    Else
        wsClient.Cells(i, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F:F"), "<=" & Cells("f2"))
    End If
Next i

End sub
```

Comment: Change `Cells("F2")` to `wsClient.Cells(i, 6)`

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you!